# Does Thomson and Rayleigh Scattering cause any change in rotational and vibrational energy of an electron or atom?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, atomic-physics, scattering, spectroscopy

We know from molecular spectroscopy that incoming light on a molecule can change a molecule's rotational, vibrational and electronic energy levels.

If the incoming light is,

- on the *far-infrared* and *microwave* *region* the molecule gets **rotational energy**.(**microwave spectra**)
- on the *near-infrared* *region* the molecule gets both rotational and **vibrational energy**.(infrared spectra)
- on the *ultraviolet* & *visible light region*, the molecule gets all energy levels rotational, vibrational, and **electronic energy** (**electronic band spectra**)

We also know that,

- Rayleigh Scatter **does not** excite electrons of atoms to another electronic
  level but only causes them to oscillate.
- Thomson Scatter happens when an electron is free or quasi-free and it also makes the electron oscillate and more, accelerate.

**Taking into account that** both Rayleigh and Thomson most probably happen at **low energies** and vibrational and rotational energy changes of **molecules** happen at microwave and infrared spectra:

**QUESTION:**

It is clear that,

- Thomson Scattering **can not** cause rotational spectra *or energy
  build-up*, which requires the whole molecule to rotate since Thomson
  Scattering is about free and *quasi-free electrons*. **But what about
  vibrational energy spectra, or energy build-up on such a free electron?**
- Rayleigh Scattering happens on the atomic level so it begs the question, "can it cause **both** rotational and vibrational energy level changes in atoms or molecules?"

Comment: I know that they both are elastic scattering which means incoming light does not lose energy but I asked this question anyways.

Comment: "Elastic scattering", from the light's perspective, is an approximation. A change in the direction of the wave vector of the light has to require a momentum transfer, which means that the atom is not at rest any longer in its original rest system. It just happens that the rest mass of an atom is much larger than the energy of the photons involved (by nine to eleven orders of magnitude for optical wavelengths), so we can neglect that energy transfer. The process can only be "truly elastic" if we count both kinetic energy terms.

Comment: FlatterMann is yet again just plain wrong. The elastic scattering is _defined_ as the case that the incoming particles have the opposite but same momentum coming in, in the centre of momentum frame, and exit with momentum of the same magnitude, and hence necessarily also conserving the energy of each. The interesting thing is that there are parameter regimes whereby this is not just possible, but rather the dominant interaction. When elastic scattering is not the case, then it is called inelastic.